# What does the Access Modifier option actually do in a RESX file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx, access-modifiers

When modifying a RESX file, I've noticed the "Access Modifier" option in the top toolbar.

[image]

There are three different options: **public**, **internal**, and **no code generation**. I'm guessing these determine which applications have access to these resource files, but I'm not exactly sure what the difference between the three options are.

1. I would assume **public** resources can be accessed from any project within the solution.
2. I would assume **internal** resources can only be accessed by the project in which the resource is defined.
3. I don't know what **no code generation** does.

What do the three options actually mean?

Comment: Along the resx file you get a class named after your resource file with properties to easily access the resources in your resx file. The Access Modifier is for the visibility of this generated class. Or in case of 3 that you won't get such a class and have to do the hardwork at getting the resources out of the resx yourself. Like creating a Resourcmanager, loading the resource file, locating the entry etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions about 1 and 2 are correct.

Try setting the access modifier of a resource item which is used **outside** of the project in which it was defined from 'Public' to 'Internal' and then build your project again.  You will get compiler errors similar to :

error CS0122: 'Resource' is inaccessible due to its protection level

3. 'No code generation' means a designer file like 'Resource.Designer.cs' doesn't get created:

[image]